# Is it possible to render OpenGL to a WebGL context?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, npapi

This is a strange question, but is it possible to pass a WebGL context to a browser plugin and have the plugin draw to it as it would to an OpenGL ES 2.0 context?

I have heard this might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browser (version) this might be possible through obscure, lowest level tinkering hacks; I don't recommend it.

But there's a way to use a WebGL canvas from a plugin: The WebGL context it part of the DOM, so it is perfectly possible to use the WebGL context through the DOM, and since plugins have full access to the DOM, a plugin can control the WebGL context. The same holds true for Java applets, which is a really nice thing as it allows to use OpenGL in a Java applet without requiring the website visitor to install JoGL or allow insecure access.

Answer (score 1):

I can guarantee this would not work in general; on the Mac at least you can't just pass OpenGL contexts across processes, and most of the major browsers now on the Mac run plugins in a different process from the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome implements WebGL through *Direct3D* on Windows. So that's never going to work. There is no guarantee that any WebGL context is being implemented on top of a desktop OpenGL implementation.

Comment: I'm still puzzled why Google does it that way. After all it's not just the API calls that must be translated. It's also the GLSL source that must be translated, along with the whole Uniform, Vertex Attribute semantics and a few other nontrivial things.

Comment: DirectX support is sometimes better than OpenGL support with some drivers.

Comment: @echeese: While this is true, I'd say Google has so much weight in the computer industry that by founding Chrome/Windows WebGL on OpenGL, they could easily force graphics vendors to get their OpenGL driver act together, simply by not using DirectX. Well, Google's slogan is "Don't be evil." but that doesn't imply "Be good!"

Comment: That'd be a lot harder for them to co-ordinate. Not all vendors support some of their older hardware, and not all users will update their drivers. Simply put, the easiest thing for them to do was just use DirectX on Windows, which tends to be less buggy on certain configurations. Having the browser crash to prove a point to graphics vendors is a pretty evil thing to do.

Comment: @echeese: Frankly, when people report "problems" with one of my programs, that is actually a bug in the OpenGL driver then I simply tell them, that this is not a bug in my program, but in the OpenGL driver and that they shall complain to the vendor about driver quality. I usually report a bug myself, but having a userbase doing the same thing adds gravity.

Comment: @datenwolf: Some people don't care where the bug is. They see your program acting up, and therefore your program is responsible. Period. That's simply how it is with regular users.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Say you have a buggy NIC driver that corrupts emails, webpages, etc. and the user complains to the browser developer, what would the browser developer say? Personally I expect the operating system to behave according to spec, otherwise it's broken and must be fixed.

Comment: @datenwolf: That's the nature of customer service: most users don't care who's fault it technically is. The program that is visibly acting up is the program that's responsible. Customers really don't care that something is not behaving according to spec; they want their stuff _working_, and since you gave them the program that seems broken, they expect you to get it working. They don't care about the technical details of why it isn't working. So if using D3D makes Chrome WebGL work more often and more reliably than using OpenGL, then it makes sense for Google to do that.